# How do I match the feed to what I see in the browser?

Tags: support, feed

I'm trying to match the questions I see on this page:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=month

To an RSS feed, e.g.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/month

But I'm seeing different results. Even if I try sorting by votes, the results are different:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/month?sort=vote

Comment: You do realize that the feeds link you're using is for Meta *Stack Overflow* but the questions page you linked is for Meta *Stack Exchange*, a different site? Was that a mistake in your question or are you simply looking at two completely different sites?

Comment: Thanks. It was a mistake, but I still think the results are different.

Comment: Now that I'm using the correct sites, meta actually seems fairly comparable. But I originally found the issue with gamedev.stackexchange where the results seem more widely divergent.